# ErrorException Undefined variable: usuarios

Tags: php, laravel-8, blade

realizaba la funcion de edit y update en laravel 8. Cuando me salta este `ErrorException Undefined variable: usuarios ... Asumiendo que no reconoce la variablae $usuarios o $user. Ya en la vista se trae los datos de la db y muestra todo en pantalla listo para el guardado...

`, este es mi controlador de edit

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = DB::table('usuarios')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('id_us',$id)->get()->first();
    return view('dashboard.editarUser',['usuarios'=>$user]);
}
```

Y el controlador del Update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$request->validate([
'nombre'=> 'required',
'apellido'=> 'required',
'cedula'=> 'required',
'direccion'=> 'required',
'roles'=> 'required',
'telefono'=> 'required',
'correo'=> 'required',
'nom_us'=> 'required',
'clave'=> 'required',
    ]);
    $usuarios->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index')->with('success', 'Datos guardados con exito');
}
```

Comment: En tu segundo método estas haciendo esto: `$usuarios->update($request->all());` pero ¿dónde has definido a `$usuarios`?

Answer (score 0):

Es la función Update no existe la variable $usuario, debes definirla primero, se esta recibiendo el $id, por tanto debes trae el usuario que deseas actualizar falta:

```
$usuarios = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

//Y depues si lo puede actualizar
$usuarios->update($request->all());
```

O otra solución es usar model binding y recibir en el update
el $usuario https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.